# jqGrid plugin - no auto row ID?

Tags: jqgrid, row, increment, identifier

I use jqGrid javascript plugin.
I use datatype:json, and everything works fine, beside the fact I don't want jqGrid to give IDs to my rows.

I don't want to set IDs at all, and if I don't set them, jqGrid automatically gives IDs to rows : 1, 2, 3.. (auto-increment numbers). This is a problem since I create a few grids , and then I have the same ID multiple times. 
Though I haven't had any problems with it so far, I don't want my document to be invalid. Is there any way to disable jqGrid auto row ID ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every row of data of the grid **must have** `id` attribure. It will be used in many callbacks of jqGrid. So I recommend you to assign some value. If you get the data from the server the data will be typically get from some table of the database which do have unique id. In the case I recommend you to use the value as the id. It will simplify the implementation of editing of the data it you will decide to implement the feature in the future.

To assign **unique** id value on the client side I can suggest you two approaches: 1) usage of `idPrefix` 2) usage of `beforeProcessing` to assign unique `id` attribute to every item returned from the server *on the client side*.

The first approach is very easy. The rowid will be constructed from the value of `idPrefix` option of the grid and the id from input data or 1,2,3,... values generated by jqGrid if no ids are found in the input data. For example you can use `idPrefix: "a"` for the first grid and `idPrefix: "b"` for the second grid. In the case ids of the first grid will be `"a1"`, `"a2"`, `"a3"`, ... and ids of the second grid will be `"b1"`, `"b2"`, `"b3"`, ...

In case of usage the second approach you need to implement `beforeProcessing` callback which will be called by jqGrid after response from the server are get, but before the data will be processed by jqGrid. So you will be able to *pre-process* the data. For example you can make a loop over the items of data and assign `id` attribute to every item with `$.jgrid.randId()` for example. The method `$.jgrid.randId()` will generate unique id value. So you will have no id dupplicates more.

Comment: Thanks. though I could easily give id in my server, as I do server-side loop on the data. But I prefered not to do so. I'll use the idPrefix option.

Comment: @user3599803: Small remark **not about my answer**. You used voting only 2 times in 5 months. Voting is the main may **to help other people** to find **really helpful** information on stackoverflow. Voting is the main criteria for sorting. You have rite to vote up to 30 answers or questions **per day** (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/147495)). So if you what help other users please vote all helpful answers and questions which you find on the stackoverflow.

Comment: sorry. I thought marking in V would be enough. upvoted you in every relevant question.

Comment: @user3599803: No problem. I thought that you misunderstood the meaning of voting. So I decided to inform you about it. Please use in the future voting of all interesting information which you find on the stackoverflow and not only answers on your questions.

Comment: @Oleg that is true and I Agree!